# How to apply multiple if then else statement?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax, powerquery

I'm hoping to develop an excel model that will use powerpivot/and power query to extract a large amount of data from a data warehouse and then perform a series of actions based on certain rules.

I've managed the first part, however, I'm struggling with applying the rules. In short, the model should work by first checking if rule 1 is correct, if not then it should check if rule 2 is correct, if not rule 3 and so.

It is possible that more than 1 rule is correct, however, the action applied should be based on the order of the rule.

A series of if statements might work but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Appreciate any help/suggestions.

[Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozHQb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is one way to do it, by using an outer join.

If you have a table for your rules (Rules):
[image]

And a table for your records (Records):
[image]

You can merge your Variable columns within each table and then merge (join) the two tables, using the new merged variable columns of the Rules and Records tables as the key match; and then split the merged variable column that's in the new merged table, to ultimately get this table of comparison results (Comparison):
[image]

Here's the M code from the Rules table:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Rule #", Int64.Type}, {"Variable 1", type text}, {"Variable 2", type text}, {"Variable 3", type text}, {"Variable 4", type text}, {"Variable 5", type text}}),
#"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Demoted Headers",{"Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in
#"Merged Columns"
```

Here's the M code from the Records table:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table15"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Record", type text}, {"Variable 1", type text}, {"Variable 2", type text}, {"Variable 3", type text}, {"Variable 4", type text}, {"Variable 5", type text}}),
#"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Demoted Headers",{"Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in
#"Merged Columns"
```

And here's the M code from the Comparison table:

```
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(Records,{"Merged"},Rules,{"Merged"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.FullOuter),
#"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "NewColumn", {"Column1"}, {"NewColumn.Column1"}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Expanded NewColumn","Merged",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv),{"Merged.1", "Merged.2", "Merged.3", "Merged.4", "Merged.5"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Merged.1", type text}, {"Merged.2", type text}, {"Merged.3", type text}, {"Merged.4", type text}, {"Merged.5", type text}}),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Rule #", "Rule # Matched"}})
in
#"Renamed Columns"
```